# How to merge code that contains custom calls into a common method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv

I'm seeding many database tables from csv files always using similar code. Only two things change for each table (see below). Do you see any way to merge the table-seeding into a common method to get cleaner code?

It's easy to have the file name as an argument to a common method. But I'm not sure what to do with the AddOrUpdate() call. The number of columns and column types are different for tables.

Any idea is much appreciated.

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("file1.csv") // #### this file name ####
{
  parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
  parser.SetDelimiters(",");

  while (!parser.EndOfData)
  {
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Col1,
      new Table1Type() { Col1 = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]), Col2 = fields[1] });
      // #### this row ####
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddOrUpdate` just takes a `Func` signature returning an object, so you could make a custom method or class that takes the file name as a parameter, and the func of how to build the object for the `AddOrUpdate` call as the other parameter.

```
private void DoWork(string fileName, Func<string[], object> fieldParser)
{
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Col1, fieldParser(fields));
        }
    }
}
```

Call like so:

```
DoWork("file1.csv", fields => { new Table1Type() { Col1 = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]), Col2 = fields[1] });
```

This may not be **entirely** correct since I don't know your DB Context structure, but this is the basic idea of using functions as first class members in .NET...

Comment: That's helpful, many thanks. Unfortunately, this puts all data into `Table1`. Can the table name be referenced in an argument somehow?

Comment: Not easily. You'd likely need reflection, and a pattern (such as table name matching csv name, or passing table name as a parameter and using it to find the property on the context).